# The following RangeError was thrown building: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1

Tags: android, flutter, dart, listview, mobile

The following RangeError was thrown building:
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1

how can I rectify this error, Can you please tell me what's the issue with my code and how to avoid showing that red screen error in my app?

It displays a red [image]screen

```
  List<String> attachments = [];
 
  List<String> imageName = [];

  bool isHTML = false;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
 

   

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
       
        ),
        builder: (context) => Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: ListView(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: kRegularPadding),
                  
                 
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: _addImage,
                        child: SizedBox(
                            width: 343.h,
                            height: 165.h,
                            child: Image.asset(
                              AssetImagePaths.uploadImage,
                              fit: BoxFit.contain,
                            )),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: kLargePadding,
                      ),
                      ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        itemCount: attachments.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Padding(
                            padding:
                                EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: kRegularPadding),
                            child: Container(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                              height: 75.h,
                              width: 343.h,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                  border: Border.all(color: gray7Color)),
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    height: 43,
                                    width: 43,
                                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                      color: navy5Color,
                                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                    ),
                                    child: const Icon(
                                      Icons.insert_drive_file,
                                      color: navy1Color,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    width: kSmallPadding,
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: Text(
                                      imageName[index],
                                      style: Theme.of(context)
                                          .textTheme
                                          .caption!
                                          .copyWith(
                                              color: gray3Color,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  const Spacer(),
                                  Text(
                                    "100%",
                                    style: Theme.of(context)
                                        .textTheme
                                        .caption!
                                        .copyWith(
                                            color: gray3Color,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    width: kSmallPadding,
                                  ),
                                  IconButton(
                                    onPressed: () => {_removeAttachment(index)},
                                    icon: const Icon(
                                      Icons.cancel,
                                      color: gray3Color,
                                      size: 24,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      )

                 
                      ,
                      SizedBox(
                        height: kRegularPadding,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: kMediumPadding),
                ],
              ),
            ));
  }

  void _removeAttachment(int index) {
    setState(() {
      attachments.removeAt(index);
    });
  }

 

  Future<void> _addImage() async {
    final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
    final XFile? image = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    print(image?.path);
    if (image != null) {
      setState(() {
        String _imagePath = image!.path;
        attachments.add(_imagePath);
        imageName = [_imagePath.split('/').last];
        print(_imagePath.split('/').last);
      });
    }
  }
```

**Being able to add more than 5 images.**

Comment: Set ListView.builder's itemCount: attachments.length, as itemCount: imageName.length,

Comment: doesn't work I have tried it also, thanks

Comment: kindly check ur  attachments.length is working as usual. this is causing error. this error happens when ur items length exceeded the length than defined in itemCount:.... when this error occurs.. like after adding or something ?  &

Comment: Have you checked logcat for a callstack ?

Comment: Yes I have checked the call stack for the app

Answer (score 0):

I think you just made mistake here.

```
Future<void> _addImage() async {
    final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
    final XFile? image = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    print(image?.path);
    if (image != null) {
      setState(() {
        String _imagePath = image!.path;
        attachments.add(_imagePath);
        imageName.add(_imagePath.split('/').last);  <------- just need to add name in the list
        print(_imagePath.split('/').last);
      });
    }
```

Comment: error still persist it is a range error and it isn't from here.

Answer (score 0):

**This was the answer to it**

```
 Future<void> _addImage() async {
    final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
    final XFile? image = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    print(image?.path);
    if (image != null) {
      setState(() {
        // String _imagePath = image.path;
        attachments.add(image.path.split('/').last);

        // imageName = [_imagePath.split('/').last];
        // print(_imagePath.split('/').last);
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you have used attachments list length as item count but you are getting value from imagename list that can have different lengths of the list that are making this error.   Use a model list instead of a string list.